# Creating a vector containing the next 10 row-column values for each pandas row

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, numpy, apply

I am trying to create a vector of the previous 10 values from a pandas column and insert it back into the pandas data frame as a list in a cell.

The below code works but I need to do this for a dataframe of over 30 million rows so it will take too long to do it in a loop.

Can someone please help me convert this to a numpy function that I can apply. I would also like to be able to apply this function in a groupby.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1,20)),columns = ['A'])

df.insert(0,'Vector','')
df['Vector'] = df['Vector'].astype(object)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df['Vector'].iloc[index] = list(df['A'].iloc[(index-10):index])
```

I have tried in multiple ways but have not been able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add a small sample dataframe, and share the expected output after the operation is performed

Comment: the first 3 lines of code build the df and the for loop creates the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['New']=[df.A.tolist()[max(0,x-10):x] for x in range(len(df))]
df
Out[123]: 
     A                                      New
0    1                                       []
1    2                                      [1]
2    3                                   [1, 2]
3    4                                [1, 2, 3]
4    5                             [1, 2, 3, 4]
5    6                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
6    7                       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
7    8                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
8    9                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
9   10              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
10  11          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
11  12         [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
12  13        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
13  14       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
14  15      [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
15  16     [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
16  17    [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
17  18   [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
18  19  [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you this works - How does x here relate to the index though?